# Boy with dino robots created by his grandpa

Tags: story-identification, anime

Can anybody tell me the name of the anime or cartoon, I don't remember which was it, where a boy uses the dinosaur robots in the story, and later finds out that those robots were created by his grandfather, when checks under there circuitry and finds his grandfather's symbol or logo. It must be about 15 years or older, I used to watch it in 2008 something, and it was aired with before Princess Tutu.

Comment: Is this Dinosaur King? https://youtu.be/CrwH5TUmaAQ

Comment: @SatelliteofSin: If you think it's a valid match, you should post it as an answer.